# Xamarin iOS RestSharp request hangs every X requests

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, restsharp

I'm experiencing some problems with POST requests to my server (https/ssl).

The problem is that every X requests, a request just hangs and seems not to be sent to the server, at least that what I think after sniffing an iPhone using fiddler.

Sometimes I get this message after a few minutes:

Error getting response stream (ReadDone1): ReceiveFailure

and the innerException stack trace:

at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.EndRead (IAsyncResult ar) [0x0003d] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.43/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/NetworkStream.cs:322 at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.InternalReadCallback (IAsyncResult result) [0x0002c] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.4.0.43/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:659

**Did anyone encounter such a problem or have an idea how to solve it?**

This is the code I'm using:

```
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (delegate {
        if (Utilities.IsOnline ()) {
            refreshData ();
        }
    });

    private void refreshData() {
            try {
            baseRequest = new BaseRequest ();
            baseRequest.id = "userid";

            string BaseUrl = "my server url";

            client = new RestClient ();
            client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;
            client.Timeout = 5000;

            request = new RestRequest (Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.Resource = "GetClientData";
            request.AddBody (baseRequest);

            serviceResponse = new ServiceResponse ();

            client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
                if (response.ErrorException != null) {
                    serviceResponse.payload = string.Empty;
                    serviceResponse.statusCode = StatusCode.Error;
                } else {
                    //parse data
                }

            });

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
}
```

Comment: Your blocks aren't lining up. The closing parenthesis for `client.ExecuteAsync` is actually coming after the closing curly brace for your outside `try` block, which is wrong.

Comment: I will check it, I copied part of the code and probably missed seomthing. The code itself is fine and works most of the time.

Comment: Still getting the error? I wonder if it's just a transient network connectivity issue to your server.

Comment: Yes, still getting the error every few requests and also got feedback from users who get it on iPhone from time to time.